# Native heap tracking issue - "Native Heap" tab is empty

Tags: android, memory, native, ddms

I want to track the native heap in my application.

I opened DDMS from /tools sdk's folder, as I saw in tutorials, and I do see the
"Native Heap" tab.

However when I press the "Update heap" Icon, the native heap is still empty - I don't see
any information there.

Tried that on two devices, one of them is rooted.

How do I solve this problem?

thanks!

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had faced the same issue and manage to fix using the emulator. I had to  put a file in /data called `local.prop` with `libc.debug.malloc = 1`. Than I had to close and start the emulator again. Probably it could work with the rooted mobile too (I am taking a guess).

Comment: tried that on the rooted phone, but without success. still nothing in native heap.

Comment: did you try with the emulator?

Answer (score 1):

May be http://bricolsoftconsulting.com/how-to-enable-native-heap-tracking-in-ddms/ can help... I tried and succeded with rooted phone as well as emulator.

Comment: instead of only pointing to a link better describe the key points. Or post the link as a comment